# How to apply specific columns to sapply function in R?

Tags: r

For example:

```
sapply(cars[2:3], FUN = IQR)
```

But how about if I wanted index 2 and 5? Also instead of indexes is there any way to use the column names instead?

Comment: `cars` datasets have only two columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Apply() function on specific dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503177/r-apply-function-on-specific-dataframe-columns)

Comment: Also dplyr examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21644848/5325862) (`summarise_at`), a few [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21295936/5325862) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43620936/5325862) that should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use anonymous function

```
sapply(names(cars)[1:2], function(x) IQR(cars[[x]]))
```

---

If we wanted columns 2 and 5, use `c` instead of seq operator (using a different dataset as `cars` have only two columns)

```
sapply(mtcars[c(2, 5)], IQR)
#   cyl drat  
# 4.00 0.84
```

Comment: If we pass a vector for example with 2, 5, can we also use the column names?

Comment: @MilesMorales  Either you can use numeric index or names.  It doesn't make sense to subset the names with a numeric index and then get the columns. i.e. `v1 <- c(2, 5)` we can directly do `sapply(mtcars[v1], IQR)` instead of `sapply(mtcars[names(mtcars)[v1]], IQR)` though both give the same answer

Comment: I confirmed this works! sapply(cars[c("price","passengers")], FUN = IQR), appreciate the help!

Comment: Will do! It's just stack overflow makes you wait a few minutes before allowing an answer. Thanks for the speedy resolution!